# Is it a reliable behavior that only one process receives a UDP packet when listening on a forked socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, fork

I have a server application that reads from a single udp socket. 
The application is forked x times after a bind() to the socket, so that all workers can read from the same socket using a blocking call of recvfrom().

All my tests have shown that only one process returns when a packet is received, following a first come first served pattern.

Is that a reliable behavior or do I need to expect multiple processes to return for one and the same packet once in a while?

Comment: yes, it's normal. e.g. consider Apache in pre-fork mode. You'll have some number of apache children, all listening to port 80. Imagine the chaos if ALL of those children each handled the exact same request. e.g. an online banking portal, and you do a bill payment. Suddenly your payment turns into 50 payments, because 50 apache children each grabbed the request. Now you're broke.

Comment: HTTP is built upon TCP, may this be a difference? Apache might be using a dispatcher process which distributes the packets to one of the many processes, is there any proof (e.g. source code) that they're doing it the way I described?

Comment: UDP is unreliable, and includes little in the way of message integrity checking.  And the internet is unreliable.  A given message could be duplicated by some random broken bit of internet it crosses over, and you could get two identical packets instead of one. Or a corrupted copy of a packet. Or a chicken rendered in ascii for no good reason. So no, you cannot reliably expect the User Datagram Protocol to reliably have one message arrive for each one sent, or even at most one message. It is known as the Unreliable Datagram Protocol for a reason., even if your local stack is friendly.

Comment: @Yakk: Good point!
@MarcB: It seems that apache is using some sort of mutex to deny multiple receives at the same time, so only one process at a time may actually call the `accept` function on the socket (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mpm_common.html#acceptmutex)

Comment: @Yakk I can only hope for a world where I get a chicken rendered in ascii for no good reason. Who needs a good reason for a chicken rendered in ascii?

Comment: @MarcB The behaviour of a TCP listening socket has no apparent bearing on the behaviour of a UDP receiving socket.

Comment: @Yakk Good points, but it is actually known as the *User* Datagram Protocol. See the RFC

Comment: @EJP Try Ctrl-F "User" -- I named it User Datagram Protocol.  I also said it was known as a different name for a reason.

Answer (score -1):

This is how datagram sockets work: a datagram gets delivered to only one thread/process.

And, in fact, how all sockets work. Each socket has an associated kernel send and receive buffers. `read/recv/recvfrom/recvmsg` on a socket atomically consumes from the receive socket buffer into a user-space buffer, kernel does not care which thread or process is reading from that socket. There may be more than one file descript**or** referring to the same kernel file descript**ion** referring to that socket (e.g., `dup`, `fork`), or many kernel file descript**ions** referring to the same socket (e.g. multiple processes opened the same unix or UDP (non-multicast) socket using the same filesystem name or `addr:port`).

Only for multi-cast sockets the kernel creates separate per-thread/process kernel socket structures and in this case the lower networking layer duplicates received datagrams into each socket buffer, so that each thread/process gets a copy of it.

Some people used UDP and UNIX sockets in-process for thread pools: producers would post a datagram into a socket, multiple consumer threads listen on the same socket and only one of these threads receives a datagram.

Comment: Is there any kind of widely accepted paper that proofs this fact? An RFC or the like?

Comment: What happens between threads receiving on the same socket has nothing to do with what happens between processes receiving on different sockets, or the same forked socket. The mechanisms concerned are quite different.

Comment: @EJP not sure with what exactly you disagree.